# Next.js: When deployed to Vercel, the exact same prefetching of ISR is done in double or triple

Tags: next.js, vercel

When deployed to Vercel, the exact same prefetching of ISR is done in double or triple.

This means that `getStaticProps` for the exact same page will be done twice or three times.

This problem does not occur in the local environment.

I've got `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` coded as shown below.
I don't think there is any problem.

I have been struggling with this problem for a very long time.
If you know any cause or information, I would be grateful for your help.

```js
export function getStaticPaths() {
  return { fallback: 'blocking', paths: [] };
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const { list, pk } = params!;

  if (list) resetServerContext();

  try {
    const to = `/videos/${pk}/`;
    const [firstResponse, secondResponse] = await Promise.all([
      api.get(to),
      api.get(`/videos/${pk}/related/`),
    ]);

    return {
      props: {
        relatedVideos: secondResponse.data,
        to,
        video: firstResponse.data,
      },
      revalidate: 60 * 15,
    };
  } catch {
    return { notFound: true };
  }
};
```

[image]

Comment: How are you verifying that `getStaticProps` gets called multiple times for a given pages?

Comment: If you fill in console.log in getStaticProps, you will see the log multiple times in Function logs of Vercel's administration page. You can also check that the API server has been accessed continuously.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, were you able to resolve it @Jvn

Comment: This seems to be a problem that has existed for more than 6 months by Vercel. I used SSR's Chache-control stale-while-revalidate instead.